# ServiceStack and .NET Core Middleware

Tags: asp.net-core, authorization, servicestack, middleware

I wonder if it is possible to use ServiceStack on .NET core along with middleware.

My use case is that I'd like to have API implemented with ServiceStack, and use authorisation policies and openid connect middleware such as IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation.

If no, is there any alternative way to setup ServiceStack to work with openid connect server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can register .NET Core Middleware in the same AppHost as ServiceStack in .NET Core Apps since [ServiceStack is just another middleware in the pipeline itself](http://docs.servicestack.net/netcore#net-core-startup) but ServiceStack built-in [Authentication attributes and features](http://docs.servicestack.net/authentication-and-authorization) wont be aware about any external Authentication implementations.

For a more integrated solution check out the community contributed  [ServiceStack.Authentication.IdentityServer](https://github.com/MacLeanElectrical/servicestack-authentication-identityserver) which includes a ServiceStack AuthProvider for IdentityServer.

Comment: ServiceStack.Authentication.IdentityServer has some limitations, i.e. it uses Introspection endpoint to validate tokens, which I'd like to avoid.

Is there a nice way to use both, i.e. custom filter or custom auth provider that internally uses the logic of AccessTokenValidation?

Comment: @Eugene I'm not familiar with IdentityServer so couldn't say, but Global Filters + Filter Attributes is how to execute custom logic before filters are called. My first approach would be to create a Filter Attribute like [Authenticate](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/AuthenticateAttribute.cs) which checks the incoming Request for a token. If your .NET Core filter can add something in HttpContext.Items you can access the underlying .NET Core Request in ServiceStack with `(HttpRequest)req.OriginalRequest`.

Answer (score 3):

I glued ServiceStack and .NET Core with the following code. I am not sure if it is the best way to archive the goal, but so far it works.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class AuthorizeAttribute : RequestFilterAsyncAttribute, IAuthorizeData
{
    public AuthorizeAttribute(ApplyTo applyTo)
        : base(applyTo)
    {
        Priority = -100;
    }

    public AuthorizeAttribute()
        : this(ApplyTo.All)
    {
    }

    public string Policy { get; set; }
    public string Roles { get; set; }
    public string AuthenticationSchemes { get; set; }

    public override async Task ExecuteAsync(IRequest req, IResponse res, object requestDto)
    {
        var policyProvider = req.TryResolve<IAuthorizationPolicyProvider>();
        var filter = new AuthorizeFilter(policyProvider, new[] {this}); 
        var webRequest = req.OriginalRequest as HttpRequest;

        var actionContext = new ActionContext(webRequest.HttpContext, new RouteData(), new ActionDescriptor());
        var context = new AuthorizationFilterContext(actionContext, new List<IFilterMetadata>());
        await filter.OnAuthorizationAsync(context);
        if (context.Result is ChallengeResult)
        {
            res.StatusCode = 401;
            res.EndRequest();
        }
        else if (context.Result is ForbidResult)
        {
            res.StatusCode = 403;
            res.EndRequest();
        }
    }
}
```